# Add mac efi partition from sdb (second disk) to efi boot order with efibootmgr

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, mac, efibootmgr

I am on ubuntu 20.04 (server no gui) and have two phyiscals disks (sda, sdb)
The computer is a mac mini from year 2010 with only ubuntu installed, no macos.
As this is my home server i want to make a disk backup to image files from both disks using the dd command. For this task i wanted to boot from an external bootable usb drive. (Containing an installed bootable mac os)
Normaly i press the ALT key to enter the macos efi boot menu but this seems not to work. I figured out, that the mac os efi boot partitions are on sdb, but ubuntu boots from sda.

Here is an output from `sudo efibootmgr -v`

```
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 4 seconds
BootOrder: 0080,0000,0001
Boot0000* debian        HD(1,GPT,cb2ce21f-937f-4ae2-bf1d-3c4b18c8c767,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\debian\shimx64.efi)
Boot0001* ubuntu        HD(1,GPT,40131ba1-f416-4eac-b91d-d1b6fed02a9c,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0080* Mac OS X      PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0xa,0x0)/Sata(0,0,0)/HD(3,GPT,66ff9d2a-650e-49d9-93f7-b6b02c280383,0xd604128,0x40000)
BootFFFF*       PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x4,0x1)/USB(3,0)/HD(2,0,00000000000000000000000000000000,0xe68,0x1f00)/File(\EFI\BOOT\BOOTX64.efi)
```

And here the output from `sudo parted -l`

```
Model: ATA OCZ-VERTEX2 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 115GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB   537MB   fat32              boot, esp
 2      538MB   1612MB  1074MB  ext4
 3      1612MB  115GB   113GB


Model: ATA Hitachi HTS54503 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 320GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size   File system  Name                  Flags
 1      20.5kB  210MB  210MB  fat32        EFI System Partition  boot, esp
 2      210MB   319GB  319GB  ext4         Macintosh HD
 3      319GB   320GB  650MB  hfs+         Recovery HD


Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-lv--0: 113GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End    Size   File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  113GB  113GB  ext4
```

So i guess i need to add the `EFI System Partition` from sdb to the bootorder of uefi boot using `efibootmanager`

Am i right? And if so, how can i do that.
The goal should be, that if i press the ALT key on the keyboard the macos boot menu should be shown.